# pre-commit not using virtual environment

Tags: python-3.x, git, pre-commit-hook, pre-commit, pre-commit.com

I added this to `pre-commit-config.yml`

```
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: python-hook
        name: python-hook
        entry: python python_script.py
        language: python
        pass_filenames: false
```

Where `python_script.py` has the following content

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import os

print(os.environ["VIRTUAL_ENV"])

import requests
```

The package `requests` is installed inside the active virtual environment, when I run pre-commit I get this output

```
/path/to/home/.cache/pre-commit/repouecs3sp4/py_env-python3.7
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "python_script.py", line 7, in <module>
    import requests
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'requests'
```

The issue here is that the path to the virtual environment is apparently switched to a different one `/path/to/home/.cache/pre-commit/repouecs3sp4/py_env-python3.7`.

Is there something I'm missing here? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 22, accepted):

kind of the point of pre-commit is it installs tools in isolated environments so they don't interfere with whatever state your current development environment is in -- `language: python` tells pre-commit to create its own `python` virtualenv

if you don't want that you can use `language: system` -- but this is the unsupported escape hatch for when you don't want managed tools (and note that pre-commit won't provision those environments for your contributors so they will need to make sure they have the particular environment set up and activated)

the *better* way is to declare the dependencies your `local` hook needs to pre-commit such that it can provision an environment for you using [`additional_dependencies`](https://pre-commit.com/#config-additional_dependencies) -- for example if you needed `packaging` in your tool:

```yaml
repos:
-   repo: local
    hooks:
    -   id: python-hook
        name: python-hook
        entry: python python_script.py
        language: python
        pass_filenames: false
        additional_dependencies: [packaging]
```

note again that pre-commit does not install from the repository under test (if it did, caching would be difficult-to-intractable) so you cannot use things like `-r requirements.txt` in `additional_dependencies`)

---

disclaimer: I created pre-commit

Comment: I'm trying to have pre-commit check if my Python project's requirements.txt matches pip freeze (for my current venv) - is there a way to force it to use whatever venv the committer is currently using?

Comment: So am I just meant to duplicate everything from pyproject.toml into .pre-commit-config.yaml?